# SQL select logic two tables

Tags: sql, group-by

I have two tables

- Customer(ID, First_Name, Last_Name, Address);
- Orders (ID, Product_Name, PRICE, Order_Date DATE, Customer_ID, Amount);

I must select last names of the customers along with the count of their orders.

output of select request must be

```
SMITH  | 0
GREG   | 2
WATSON | 0
HOLMSE | 2
RUST   | 4
FRINGE | 1
TKACH  | 3
```

Comment: Please show what you've tried. This should be pretty simple... Also, how do you expect to handle two Customers with the same last name?

Comment: So what's the question? You've tagged this with group-by, so it seems like you already know the answer, but you haven't told us what, if any, steps you've taken to solve your issue.

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit the question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following, using a `LEFT JOIN` and `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT c.Last_Name, COUNT(o.ID)
FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.ID = o.Customer_ID 
GROUP BY c.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    c.Last_Name, COUNT(o.ID)
FROM
    Customer c
        LEFT JOIN
    Orders o ON c.ID = o.Customer_ID
GROUP BY c.Last_Name
ORDER BY c.Last_Name;
```

You can do this with left join and group by on Last_Name columns.